# How does adding a new value to a set of data affect the standard deviation?

Tags: standard-deviation

For a given set of $n$ numbers with standard deviation $s$, it is my understanding that adding numbers that are far less than $s$ from the average will always reduce the variance.

1) Does this rule always apply? No edge cases?

2) Is there a formal proof?

Comment: Let's save I have the following set of numbers: {1,3,5} the mean is 3 and the standard deviation is 2. for my understanding, adding another number to the set which is far less than 1 standard deviation from the mean (for example: 4) will decrease the variance. I'm asking whether this rule always applies. And also if there's a formal proof.

Comment: The variance of $(1,3,5)$ is $8/3$, not $2^2=4$.  If you narrow the context beyond what is stated in the questions and add assumptions, such as that these values represent three independent draws from the same distribution, then an *unbiased estimator* of that distribution's variance is $8/2=4$ and its square root is $2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without any loss of generality we may (by using the mean as the origin and the standard deviation as the unit) choose units of measurement in which the $n$ numbers are $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ with $\sum x_i = 0$ and $\sum x_i^2 = n$. The variance and standard deviation are both $1$.  Let the new number be $x_0$.  The change in variance is found by subtracting $1$ from the variance of all $n+1$ numbers:

$$\eqalign{
&\frac{1}{n+1}\left(x_0^2 + \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\right)  - \left(\frac{1}{n+1}\left(x_0 + \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)\right)^2 - 1\\
&=\frac{x_0^2}{n+1} +  \frac{n}{n+1}  - \frac{x_0^2}{(n+1)^2} - 1\\
&=\frac{1}{n+1}\left(-1 + \frac{n}{n+1}x_0^2\right).
}$$

This will be negative if and only if $n x_0^2 \lt n+1$. Its sign does not depend on the units of measurement. Thus, **the variance will decrease when $x_0$ is within $\sqrt{1+1/n}$ standard deviations of the mean, it will increase when $x_0$ is further than this from the mean, and will stay the same otherwise.**

---

Note that the variance of $n$ numbers is the mean squared deviation from the mean.  It is not multiplied by $n/(n-1)$ for a bias correction, because nothing is being estimated: these are *descriptive* statistics.  However, if you do wish to use $\sqrt{(n-1)/n}$ times the standard deviation in the formulas, a little bit of algebra will show that a similar conclusion holds: the threshold between decreasing and increasing the variance is $\sqrt{1+1/n}$ times the "corrected" SD.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I think the final expression in the last line has an extra factor of $n$ in the numerator.

Comment: @Don You are not mistaken: thank you for catching that.  I will remove the extra $n.$  Fortunately, that does not change any of the subsequent analysis or conclusions.